# Data Storage & Design Using Multiple Machines?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

I need to build a system to store & maintain a huge amount (20 [TB]) of time-series data (for many different instruments), so that it would support the following requirements:

`(1) fast appends of new data, as new data comes in`
`(2) fast retrievals of existing (already stored) data`

There are 10,000 instruments and 1000 data fields (updated every 1-min) to save for each instrument. Once data is written to disk, it remains unchanged (no issues of concurrent writing/reading).

Since there would be no need for any joins whatsoever (typical query is: `give me all instruments for field 'X' on interval 'Y'`), I tend to store the data using flat binary files that will be named like this: `fieldName.timeStamp.bin`; this way, I would be able to store all the data in flat binary files (no need for a huge expense for a giant server / commercial database) and still, queries will be fast.

Since it's a lot of data (circa 20[TB]), I thought I would need some logic to distribute the files (`fieldName.timeStamp.bin`) between all of my machines. Here's what I had in mind: there will be a central machine to which all queries will be sent. this central machine (based on the field & timestamp requested) would route the query to the machine of interest, that would in turn return the requested data.

My questions are:

`(1) is this design scalable as I think it is? any drawbacks?`

`(2) is there anything I am missing here that might hurt performance?`

`(3) is it really the best way to send all queries to a central machine, that would in turn route the query to the right machine? or would it be best to directly access the` **right machine** (suppose I know which one it is ) `using NFS`?

`(4) is there a faster way than NFS to access the` **right machine** `to read data from it? are there other methods for sharing all the data that on the data machines with client machines?`

All of my machines use Ubuntu Linux. As can be understood, there will be many `client` machines that would access the various `data machines` and read (only read, not write) data from them. my goal is to have the data read as fast as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also want to take a look at [OpenTSDB](http://opentsdb.net/), a Hadoop-based system for storing and retrieving massive time-series data.  I've never used it, but it sounds handy and at least near your purposes.

Comment: Thank you. Does my design makes sense, at least?

Comment: Things to think about: will you ever be deleting or archiving data? If so, how do you support that? How many clients are you talking about? If there are relatively few clients, then at any given time a number of your data machines may be idle when they could have been serving data if you distributed the workload more evenly. Do you expect your clients to parse the `.bin` files, or would it give you better performance to have your data machines do it and only send over the query results? I suspect the latter is correct, in which case you should avoid NFS.

Comment: My comments about performance are unlikely to be that big of a deal if you're looking for bandwidth and latency to support a seek and 500KB read in 1s, though. At that point, simplicity and robustness are more likely to matter. You may want to consider storing multiple copies of the data on separate machines. What happens in your design if one data machine goes offline?

Comment: @justarobert: There very well might be 100s of clients. Here's what I have in mind though: for every single `data machine`, there will be `3 machines` that mirror it (meaning, a cron `rsync` will make 3 copies of every `data machine`). When a read request is sent, the central machine will randomize one machine out of the four (1 `data machine` + 3 `copies` = 4 machines) and use it to retrieve the requested data. if / when a `data machine` gets corrupted or there are some issues, one of the `mirrored machines` will replace it. Does it make sense?

Comment: @justarobert: I would of course be happy with MUCH BETTER PERFORMANCE that `500KB read in 1sec`. Yet, just to make this clear, what I meant was that I want a system that would support say 200 clients each (concurrently) being able to read `500KB in 1sec` (at least). Do you see any issues using NFS for this? are there better / more robust ways?

Comment: @justarobert: the clients would parse the bin files themselves. no deletion or archive of data is necessary at this point.

Comment: Your central machine will likely be able to handle 200 queries per second, but you should build in some redundancy in case it dies. If all of those queries are for the same chunk of data, the four machines with that file may have a problem. NFS as a delivery mechanism is not bad, but not great, either. Are the queries likely to return multiple `.bin` files, or will they more often only use part of a `.bin` file? If the latter, your clients should only read the part they need, to conserve bandwidth. How will you detect and fix data corruption? I still suspect that you're reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @justarobert: should the queries to the machines be sent through the 'central' machine? or should every machine be able to view the `NFS` share of all other machines? A query will load the contents of one `bin` file to memory. these files are in binary format (of size 500[KB] each), and are in the exact format I need (no more, no less). Why do you think I'm re-inventing the wheel? is there any other solution I could use?

Comment: Somehow, the clients need to know where the data files reside, if they are going to be reading the files themselves. I assumed that, in your design, the central machine would be giving out that location information, and that's what I meant above by queries.

Comment: My impression is that you are developing this system more or less from scratch. You will need to implement a query language, a protocol for your clients to communicate with the central server, a means of delivering data to the clients (currently NFS), a means of writing data coherently to the system, and some way of detecting and fixing data corruption and server failure, all while taking into account robustness, performance, and possibly security. That's a lot to do. Hadoop is currently one of the trendy technologies, I know, but its strengths fit pretty well to your needs.

Comment: @justarobert: `I assumed that, in your design, the central machine would be giving out that location information` yes, this is correct.

Comment: @justarobert: I am thinking of writing the data using `ssh`. meaning, `ssh` to every system and write the data straight to it (I have the files ready to do it). As per reading, I am not sure what's best: `ssh` to the system and read the file, or alternatively, export (using `NFS`) all data from all machines to the clients, and simply read from the `NFS` share. Any hints which way would be best?

Comment: Using `ssh` feels too heavy to me. While you can lock `ssh` down so that it only permits the write or read command you designate, it's probably more secure not to provide the login functionality in the first place, and `ssh` will definitely add some latency overhead, if not throughput overhead. If you're going that path, just use `NFS`. You'll still need to add a layer on top to figure out where to write the data and how to record the locations.

Answer (score 2):

[Tahoe Least Authority File System](http://tahoe-lafs.org/trac/tahoe-lafs) may solve many of these problems automatically, especially if you can work with their tools for retrieving the data. At least, I'd give it a look before making my own system. Without data on what the real bandwidth and latency requirements are, I can't say much more.

Comment: thank you. can you give me some pointers how to estimate the `real bandwidth and latency requirements`? Would it help if I say that I'd like every client machine to be able to read any 500KB file in one of the `data machines` in less than 1[sec]?

Comment: any feedback on my design? does it at all make sense? am I in the right direction?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the design, but I don't have any real experience with it myself (I have one 10TB file server at work, and it just offers NFS, Samba, and Appletalk to various clients). At this point, I'd start check with Tahoe's mailing lists and get their opinions. I think 500KB in 1 second would be easy to meet, though.

Answer (score 1):

A few notes:

1) Using a centralized server seems unnecessary here. Why not make a hash of the filename and use a simple sort to decide which server to store / get the files? That way you don't need a central server to store / write the files.

2) Given the scale of the system you are talking about, I would look into using Lustre or GLuster to do the file system stuff for you instead of using NFS. Let them do the hard work for you. Both are used for systems much larger then this and have a solid track record.

3) If you do decide to role your own setup, I would take a strong look at OpenSolaris / Nexenta w/ZFS. For file systems that large, some of ZFS's strengths become really helpful:

a) ZFS does intelegent raid rebuilds. I can rebuild 16tb of data on a 10x2tb raid 50 drive setup in 30 hours. Which is much faster then if I was doing the same kind of rebuild with a hardware raid card.
b) ZFS does not need to fsck, even with ext3/4 the fsck on partitions that large is going to be really painful.
c) ZFS's I/O scheduler for writes is very strong. You can add a single SSD to hold the ZIL logs / LARC2 cache and get most of the gains of a SSD based storage system with the large data retention of hard drives.
d) ZFS has a very robust NFSv4 server built in. Sharing is easy to configure.
e) ZFS has built in file system level de-duplication which might be a huge win for you if the instrument readings often return similar results.

Comment: thank you. Regarding (1), you are right. The problem is, if I don't 'send' the WRITES through a 'central' machine, then in order to be able to read/write FAST, I will need every machine to have an open `SSH` connection to all other machines at all times. is it a porblem?   also, I am not familiar with the other filesystems; would it be so bad to use `ext4` if every machine only stores say 500[GB] of data on it?  would I still need `ZFS` or `Lustre`?  (are they hard to install / maintain) ?